# how to remove image from filelist and upload it on server using api request?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Html multi-select to select images and applying javascript to display images.As you can see in this picture there is a cross on top of every image which removes images from UI.
So, if out of three images displayed I delete one of them and upload it on server it will upload all the three imgaes instead of two images.  [image]

my script:

```
   $(document).on('click', '.browse', function () {
            var file = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.file');
            file.trigger('click');
        });
        $(document).on('change', '.file', function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.form-control').val($(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''));
        });

        function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
            // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                if (i > 3) {

                    break;
                }

                                var reader = new FileReader();

                // Closure to capture the file information.
                reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                    return function (e) {
                        // Render thumbnail.
                        var span = document.createElement('span');
                        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumbs_image" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/> <a href="#" class="remove_pic">X</a>'
                        ].join('');
                        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);

                        span.children[1].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                            span.parentNode.removeChild(span);


                        });
                    };
                })(f);

                // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't be done like this, you can't remove a file from that html input element because selected files/images are stored in a read-only FileList object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

As an alternative you can keep your own array of files, but then you will need to use your own implementation to upload the files.

Comment: can you guide through implementation that how to delete that object list.if possible.
Thanks in advance